# Controller is not a function got undefined, http.post request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am having trouble with an instance of a controller.

I have a simple navigation tree using this module:http://nickperkinslondon.github.io/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/test/bs3_ng120_test_page.html

I added a double click function on any leaf, and a directive that compiles, and opens a window using this module: http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/cFKkG

The window contains a few tabs, and one of these tabs must contain another navigation tree, just like the first one but with different data.

I am also using http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2014/04/angularjs-getting-around-ngapp-limitations-with-ngmodule/ so I can have multiple app on the same page.

Problem is, the second navigation tree that must be loaded doesn't work. I am declaring it, in the html sent this way (moduleAbn is a variable contained in the first .js loaded at start, referecing the module App1):

```
<script> moduleAbn.controller('AbnTestController2',['\$scope','\$http','\$timeout','\$compile',function(\$scope,\$http,\$timeout,\$compile){
...}]);</script>

<div ng-module='App1'> <div ng-controller='Controller2'>
```

Doing this, the console shows the famous **Controller2 is not a function, got undefined**.

The weird thing is, if I declare it with the name of the first navigation tree controller

```
<div ng-module='App1'> <div ng-controller='Controller1'>
```

Navigation tree appears, with the same data as the first, but seems to work independently from the other.

I really don't know how do get this working with different data from the first tree...

If I am not being clear, english is not my mother tongue so I can get more specific if you have any questions ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: no other errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

You should rename `AbnTestController2` to `Controller2` when defining it or change it's name in `ng-controller=` from `Controller2` to `AbnTestController2`.

Second thing you need to check is that `App1` has module `AbnTest` as dependency:

```
var App1 = angular.module('App1', ['AbnTest'])
```

Comment: I can't remove the backslashes, ajax script is php so without backslashes, $ would be interpreted as php variables. Also I already made the change of the Controller name (wrong copy paste in my exemple sorry).

Comment: Have you changed the controller name?

Comment: Does your App1 have the other modules as dependencies?

Comment: declared it this way:                                                   var moduleAbn = angular.module('AbnTest',['angled-windows','ui.bootstrap','dynamicHTML','angularBootstrapNavTree']);

Comment: Please paste here how you defined App1 module

Comment: Thing is, if I use the first Controller name <div ng-controller='Controller1'> the navigation tree is loaded, so I guess the problem is elsewhere..

Comment: I should also mention that I've tried to use two navigation trees on the same page and this works perfectly (independantly and with different data). The problem must come from the html sent not compiled as intented or something (which is weird because using the first controller name is working...)

Comment: You gonna post the definition of App1? :)

Comment: var moduleAbn = angular.module('App1',['angled-windows','ui.bootstrap','dynamicHTML','angularBootstrapNavTree']); angularBootstrapNavTree is the module I am using for the tree

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ck0tA2N.png this is what I get using Controller1 and I get nothing in the tab using Controller2